# Extracting only the hours and minutes from a Unix Timestamp code.

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm working with php and want to convert a time scrubbed from an xml file. The time in the XML is  `<startTime>0945</startTime>`  for 9:45 and   `<startTime>1330</startTime>`  for 1:30.

I'm using   `strtotime(xml_time)`   to get the unix timestamp. But now I need to extract only the time itself. I don't need to compare it to the current time, I don't need to include any date information, and I'm not concerned with the timezone. Can anyone help me with which function to use (if different) or how to modify  `strtotime()`  to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: We are **not** a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: A Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970 UTC. How can you calculate it if you don't have a date?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton -- I guess I understand the pseudonym you picked. Yes I researched... I didn't find the answer I needed which is why I asked. It helped us get past the hurdle. Thanks jrn for the response. It did exactly what I needed.

Comment: @drmail Regardless of how you feel about my response, or how you perceived my tone, I want to push quality on StackOverflow. I'm glad you found the answer that you were looking for, but questions asked in a better way can help others find the answer as well. This platform is more than an "ask a question get an answer" website, it is here for other readers having similar issues and problems. Questions asked in an on-topic way are more likely to help others than questions that show no research or that don't have verifiable code and attempts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to extract the time parameters you need:

```
echo $time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($xml_time));
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert `1330` into `13:30` you can use any of the string manipulation functions, e.g.:

```
$input = '1330';
var_dump(mb_substr($input, 0, 2) . ':' . mb_substr($input, 2, 2));
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/qLRit)

If you feed `strtotime()` with incomplete dates it'll fill the gaps with bits from current date and using the default time zone. This will lead to random unexpected results depending on what time it is when the script runs:

```
var_dump( date('H:i:s', strtotime('0230')) );
```

> string(8) "02:30:00"

```
var_dump( date('H:i:s', strtotime('0230', mktime(1, 30, 50, 3, 26, 2017))) );
```

> string(8) "03:30:00"